# how do I serialize the following format?

Tags: xml, vb.net, class

I am wondering how to get the following format on a single property including a type. Like so:

```
**<Productname type ="Drinks">coke<Productname>**
```

**What have I tried?**

```
<XmlRoot("Productname1")> _
Public Class Productname
<XmlAttribute("Type")> Public type As String = "Drinks"


Private m_Productname As String
Public Property Productname() As String
    Get
        Return m_Productname
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_Productname = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

but the following will happen with my code

```
  <Productname1 Type="Drinks">
  <Productname >coke</Productname > 
  </Productname1>
```

I just don't understand how this works and I have been searching for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work.

```
   Public Class ProductName
        <XmlAttribute("Type")>
        Property type As String = "Drinks"
        <XmlText()>
        Property Text As String = "Coke"
    End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know it could work like this with text too.